# Sending multiple line email with google script ( Google Sheet )

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new in the script life. I would like send a email based on multiple cell values. The email is working but sometimes I have only 1 PO to sent, so my current code will be sending PO1 + 9 empty lines and my email is now super long.

I think that I need to create an IF statement but am not sure where to start.

```
function mailtest() {

  var TO = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('N3').getValue();
  var CC = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('N5').getValue();
  var SUBJECT = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('L9').getValue();
  var TEXT = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('L11').getValue();
  var TEXT2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('L13').getValue();
  var PO1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('L15').getValue();
  var PO2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('L16').getValue();
  var PO3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('L17').getValue();
  var PO4 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('L18').getValue();
  var PO5 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('L19').getValue();
  var PO6 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('L20').getValues();
  var PO7 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('L21').getValues();
  var PO8 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('L22').getValues();
  var PO9 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('L23').getValues();
  var P10 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('L24').getValues();
  var signature = Gmail.Users.Settings.SendAs.list("me").sendAs.filter(function(account){if(account.isDefault){return true}})[0].signature; 
  MailApp.sendEmail({

    to: TO,
    subject: SUBJECT,
    cc: CC,
   htmlBody: 
    TEXT+"<br><br>"+

    TEXT2+"<br><br>"+
    //here is the problem ? I dont want PO3&4&5&6 if I only have 2 PO.
    PO1+"<br>"+          
    PO2+"<br>"+
    PO3+"<br>"+
    PO4+"<br>"+
    PO5+"<br>"+
    PO6+"<br>"+
    PO7+"<br>"+
    PO8+"<br>"+
    PO9+"<br>"+
    P10+"<br><br>"+
       signature


});

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to include variables in an email only if the variable has a value.
The following code differs from yours in several ways.

- the PO values are retrieved as a whole: `sheet.getRange(15,12,10,1).getValues();`
  This enables evaluation of the contents without complicated variable handling
- the code loops through the values: `for (var i=0; i<PO.length;i++){`, and
- evaluates whether the PO has a value `if ( if (POValue){){`
- if this evaluates as yes (PO has a value), then it is added to the email text(`POText = POText+POValue+"<br>"`); otherwise, that PO is not included in the email text.

---

```
function so58564238() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "58564238";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var POText = "";
  var PO = sheet.getRange(15,12,10,1).getValues();
  for (var i=0; i<PO.length;i++){
    var POValue = PO[i][0];
     if (POValue){
      POText = POText+POValue+"<br>"       
    }
  }
  Logger.log(POText)
}
```

---

**Incorporating the mailtest**

```
function mailtest() {

  var TO = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('N3').getValue();
  var CC = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('N5').getValue();
  var SUBJECT = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('L9').getValue();
  var TEXT = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('L11').getValue();
  var TEXT2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('L13').getValue();
  var POText = "";
  var PO = sheet.getRange(15,12,10,1).getValues();
  for (var i=0; i<PO.length;i++){
    var POValue = PO[i][0]
     if (POValue){
      POText = POText+POValue+"<br>"       
    }
  }
  var signature = Gmail.Users.Settings.SendAs.list("me").sendAs.filter(function(account){if(account.isDefault){return true}})[0].signature; 
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: TO,
    subject: SUBJECT,
    cc: CC,
    htmlBody: 
    TEXT+"<br><br>"+
    TEXT2+"<br><br>"+
    POText+"<br>"+
    signature
  });

}
```

Comment: Ted first of all Thank you, your explanation do help me a lot to understand!.

now I'm trying to use your code but It seems that the var in my for has an syntax error ( based on google script ) and the variable is not blue it still black. I'm trying moving things around but I think  I don't know where to put your code to make my mailtest function work.

Thank you again

Comment: it's look like it can't find the 
var PO = sheet.getRange(15,12,1,10).getValues();

Comment: My mistake. I have edited the answer. I had made the PO data range horizontal (across row 16) instead of vertical (down column L). Changes in several rows, just copy and start again.

Comment: I've added a second edit to show where and how to incorporate the PO code. The idea is to substitute all the 10 `getValue` lines and insert the looping routine. The loop generates a variable called `POText` which you insert into the `sendEmail` method in place of the troublesome ten lines of "PO1+PO2+...etc".

Comment: Ted Thank you again, I did try the code it only show me empty cell for POs I did try changing the variables, referencing cell instant of number column and rows.. and always the same result. I did found a temporary solution:
POText is now referencing to an hidden cell ( like A2 ) and A2 is a Concatenate with a IF of all my range of PO : =if(L15<>"",L15&"<BR>","")

and now it recognize the <br> in my cell as a enter 
(return) in my email.

I know It's a temporary solution and yours is way more optimize I hope to get it working soon :) Thank you

Comment: Are your PO values strings or numbers? Better yet, share a copy of your spreadsheet.

Comment: string 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ug-UAahNqP1h2P9Tua_WPq8wGTynpr7JJPODEx2YArg/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks Ted I did remove some company information but Everything is there

Comment: @Roch-André Sorry for that; Your PO are strings, I was testing with numbers. I've modified the code. The test now is simply `if (POValue){` which returns True if there is a value (regardless of whether it is a string or number) and False if not. Should run fine. But give me access to the sheet just to confirm.

Comment: Hi Ted thanks for all your help it's now working! you are the best !

I vote for Ted as a President !

Thanks again, I am not familiar with stackoverflow, can I give you points or comments?

Thanks again